# Philosohy of Rabindranath Tagore

Tags: reference-request

Can someone provide some online and offline references which analyses the philosophies of Rabindranath Tagore (from credible sources)?

Comment: Ashgate have a number of [books](https://www.routledge.com/products/search?keywords=tagore&group=&category=&imprintcode=) looking at Tagore in a philosophical and cultural context which you might find useful.

Answer (score 3):

"The Philosophy of Rabindranath Tagore" by Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan (1918) http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7484416-the-philosophy-of-rabindranath-tagore